# Is difference of two constexpr instances of __func__ pointers still constexpr?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, c++17, constexpr

Is this valid C++?

```
int main() {
    constexpr auto sz = __func__ - __func__;
    return sz;
}
```

GCC and MSVC think it's OK, Clang thinks it's not: [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/-ChsAx).

---

All compilers agree that this one is OK: [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/NgHqmo).

```
int main() {
    constexpr auto p = __func__;
    constexpr auto p2 = p;
    constexpr auto sz = p2 - p;
    return sz;
}
```

---

Clang again doesn't like this one, but the others are OK with it: [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/CHyiM9)

```
int main() {
    constexpr auto p = __func__;
    constexpr auto p2 = __func__;
    constexpr auto sz = p2 - p;
    return sz;
}
```

---

What is up here? I think arithmetic on unrelated pointers is undefined behavior but `__func__` returns the same pointer, no? I am not sure, so I thought I may test it. If I recall correctly, `std::equal_to` can compare unrelated pointers without undefined behavior:

```
#include <functional>

int main() {
    constexpr std::equal_to<const char*> eq{};
    static_assert(eq(__func__, __func__));
}
```

Clang thinks `eq(__func__, __func__)` isn't a constant expression, even though `std::equal_to::operator()` [is constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to). Other compilers don't complain:  [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/pBV-xu)

---

Clang won't compile this one either. Complains that `__func__ == __func__` is not a constant expression: [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vV_ATV)

```
int main() {
    static_assert(__func__ == __func__);
}
```

Comment: From [Function_definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Function_definition), `__func__` is as-if `static const char __func__[] = "function-name";` and that equivalent is accepted [Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/CFmfjE)...

Comment: Interestingly, it works if you initialize a constexpr variable with `__func__` and use that in the static_assert...

Comment: @Jarod42 So this is a bug in Clang?

Comment: @florestan like [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/kbLZvJ)? It won't compile with Clang either. My 2nd and 3rd examples in the question are the way you mentioned. One compiles, the other one doesn't.

Comment: @Ayxan, ah yeah, right. Sorry...

Comment: See also [CWG1962](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1962), which might remove `__func__` entirely from constexpr evaluation.

Comment: @curiousguy [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/234735/183642) code wouldn't compile on Clang for because of the same reason. Have a look.

Comment: @Ayxan Interesting. I hope you didn't took badly my remark that `__func__ - __func__` looks like a ridiculous expression. lol

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`__func__` in C++ is an identifier. In particular, it references a specific object. From [[dcl.fct.def.general]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.def#general-8):

> The function-local predefined variable `_­_­func_­_­` is defined as if a definition of the form
>
> ```
> static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
> ```
>
> had been provided, where function-name is an implementation-defined string. It is unspecified whether such a variable has an address distinct from that of any other object in the program.

As a [function-local predefined variable](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.def#general-7), this definition (as if) appears at the beginning of the function block. As such, any uses of `__func__` within that block will refer to that variable.

As for the "any other object" part, a variable defines an object. `__func__` names the object defined by that variable. Therefore, within a function, all uses of `__func__` name the same variable. What is undefined is whether that *variable* is a distinct object from other objects.

That is, if you're in a function named `foo`, and you used the literal `"foo"` somewhere else in the problem, it is not forbidden for an implementation to have the variable `__func__` also be the same object that the literal `"foo"` returns. That is, the standard doesn't require that every function in which `__func__` appears must store data separate from the string literal itself.

Now, C++'s "as if" rule allows implementations to deviate from this, but they *cannot* do it in a way that would be detectable. So, while the variable itself may or may not have a distinct address from other objects, uses of `__func__` in the same function must behave as if they are referring to the same object.

Clang does not seem to implement `__func__` this way. It appears to implement it as if it returned a prvalue string literal of the function's name. Two distinct string literals don't have to refer to the same object, so subtracting pointers to them is UB. And undefined behavior in a constant expression context is ill-formed.

The only thing that makes me hesitant to say that Clang is 100% wrong here is [[temp.arg.nontype]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.nontype#2):

> For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, the value of the constant expression shall not refer to (or for a pointer type, shall not be the address of):
>
> ...
>
> - a predefined `_­_­func_­_`­ variable.

See, this seems to allow some fudging by the implementation. That is, while `__func__` can technically be a constant expression, you can't use it in a template parameter. It is treated like a string literal, even though it is technically a variable.

So on some level, I would say that the standard is talking out of both sides of its mouth.

Comment: So, strictly speaking `__func__` can be a constant expression in all the cases in my question, right? So the code should have compiled.

Comment: What about the "It is unspecified whether such a variable has an address distinct from that of any other object in the program." part? Unspecified behavior means non-determinism in the behavior of the abstract machine. Can that be problematic for constexpr evaluation? What if for the first occurence of `__func__` the address is the same as that of another object, and in the second occurence of `__func__` it is not? Granted, that does not mean that the address differs between the two instances, but I'm still confused!

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: "*What about the "It is unspecified whether such a variable has an address distinct from that of any other object in the program." part?*" What about it? `__func__` is not a macro; it is an identifier which names a specific variable and therefore a specific object. Therefore, any use of `__func__` in the same function should result in a glvalue that refers to the same object. Or more to the point, it cannot be implemented in such a way that this wouldn't be the case.

Comment: @Nicol that refers to the same object. But that object may at one instant have the same address as another object. And at the other instant have not. I'm not saying that is a problem, but I'm just reminding everyone of this possibility. And then after all, I may also be mistaken, so I'm also saying this in the hopes of being corrected or being confirmed.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: "*But that object may at one instant have the same address as another object.*" That's not allowed under the C++ object model. Two objects, neither one being nested within the other, cannot both be within their lifetimes in the same storage at the same time. And the object in question has static storage duration, so unless you use placement-`new` on it, it isn't going anywhere until the program ends.

Comment: @NicolBolas but it says "It is unspecified whether such a variable has an address distinct from that of any other object in the program.". You have a point here. So the consequence is that this means: "It is unspecified whether such a variable is distinct from any other object in the program".

Comment: I suspect that there's no problem with this. Just keep it in mind.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I think it's referring to if you have a string literal `"main"` elsewhere, `__func__` in the main function could have the same address as that literal. I can't think of any other ways two objects not nested one inside another could have the same address.

Comment: @Ayxan there are not necessarily two objects. Because of what NicolBolas says, another declaration of yours may declare the same object as `__func__`. I think that might be the reason why `__func__` is also disallowed as a template argument. It will be surprising to learn that `someTemplate<myGlobalArray>` is the same type as `someTemplate<__func__>`.

Comment: @NicolBolas reading it again, the spec says " from that of any other object in the program.", which implies it's an *other* object. So here we *do* have the situation that two objects, neither one being nested within the other, share the same address. So what's the solution?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Solution to what? It's saying that you cannot use `&__func__` or anything equivalent to that as a unique identifier for the object named by `__func__`. That's all. Note that it's saying the address of the *variable*, not the address of the object named by the variable.

Comment: @T.C.: I've seen that, but since it hasn't been resolved after 4+ years...